# How can I pass these values to a data frame in this order(or something similar would also work)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a very large numpy array that has 2 dimensions, one with 369 elements and the other contains 370 elements. They are all floats.
The array is designed as such: [[[-18.08621204 -18.08622591 ... -18.08850475
-18.08850187]]] ... [-45.95094274 -45.94523995 ... -44.90436858 -44.90151675]]]

My final output would be to have something like this:

```
      Column1  Column2
0 -18.473131  -45.404821 
1 -18.475842  -45.404828
2 -18.478553  -45.404834   
3 -18.481265  -45.404841  
4 -18.483976  -45.404847
```

I have no idea how to achieve this though. My (terrible) attempt at this went as following : I flattened the array and turned it into a dictionary, then I turned it into a pandas dataframe like this and named my desired column:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(di, orient='index')
data.columns = ['Column 1']
```

Then what I did to get something similar to the example I gave above was:

```
data['Column1'] = data['Column2'] < -44
```

This results in:

```
       Column1        Column2
1      -18.086212      False
2      -18.086226      False

...           ...        ...
273056 -44.910072       True
273057 -44.907220       True
273058 -44.904369       True
```

The row organization I gave in the example is very import and must be kept, since they represent converted coordinates. I achieved my first example by a selected conversion of points, but ideally it needs to be done in a bulk, which gives me that numpy array first mentioned.

**EDIT:**
So before doing everything I described above I had this DF:

```
      Column1  Column2                RGBA
   0         0    0        (0, 0, 0, 255)
   1         0    1        (0, 0, 0, 255)
              ...
 
  136529    369  368       (255,255, 255, 255)
```

Then I applied the conversions described here [Converting X, Y to lat and long](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395667/translating-x-y-coordinates-to-lat-long/) like this:

```
xx, yy = cell_transform * np.meshgrid(np.arange(369), np.arange(368))
bulkx_proj = xx
bulky_proj = yy
yy_latlng, xx_latlng = proj_latlng.transform(bulkx_proj, bulky_proj)
```

xx_latlng and yy latlng are numpy arrays and I've verified it and the values are indeed following the proper order from my original dataframe, so that part is going as expected . I then tried to store the values inside my dataframe and without changing the order by doing this:

```
df['Column1'] = xx_latlng
df['Column2'] = yy_latlng
```

But then it returns me this value error: Length of values (368) does not match length of index (136530) exactly at this point. What I expected, and desire, is for each value of the numpy array to be stored inside the dataframe and under the columns I specified.

Comment: How do you decide which two values should be next to each other in the columns?

Comment: I have the resized and verified X, Y coordinates stored in another dataframe. I get the values in the array after converting my resized X, Y to real world measures of X, Y and  converting it once more to latitude and longitude. This is achieved by the solution here(too long to describe in a comment) [link]https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/395667/translating-x-y-coordinates-to-lat-long/395680#395680[link]

Comment: It appears that you have a dictionary `di` that you're trying to turn into a DataFrame. Can you include a small sample of that dictionary so that we can test turning it into a DataFrame?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't really understand what that would result in, but if that would mean that I'd be apply the conversion to my whole dataframe properly then yes, that is what I'm trying to get. Would it help if I edit my questions with more details to explain where I got stuck? I can successfully convert all my X and Y values separately(they become numpy arrays after getting converted) but I can't pass the values to my dataframe as it gives me the value error : ValueError: Length of values (369) does not match length of index (136530)

Comment: Yes can you update your question to include: The __smallest__ possible input necessary to generate your issue, and what you expect the output to be at every step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it myself. To solve it I flattened the numpy arrays then I turned them into a series and after that I just needed to concatenate the series. The order of the data was not damaged. This was achieved using flatten() in the arrays, pd.Series(1dimensional_array) and finally pd.concat([series1, series2]).